# how to enable security for aws api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I did google search for a solution on this, but nothing came up. Does anybody know if i can implement some kind of security, for example accept form submission only from one specific domain or something similar??

Just want to mention, i already read implementation about `API keys` and `SDK` but i don't think they are much helpful, or maybe i am wrong. Also i read about `IAM` implementation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you. :)

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/

Comment: @MarkB this is similar to API key header??

Comment: My point was, if i set x-api-key: bkayZOMvuy8aZOhIgxq94K9Oe7Y70Hw55 in my header, anybody expert will understand this and will be able to mimic a false call to my api or something.

Comment: No it is not similar. Please read the documentation on API Gateway Custom Authorizers. It allows you to create **custom** authorization schemes. This will allow you to add any level of authorization you want, including the type you described in your question.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong in my opinion. The whole concept of this custom authoriser is to set a custom header value and using that as a header. For example, i am using an HTML form to submit data to this API, so i have to add this custom header in the head section of my HTML page, which is visible to all right? So, if someone figure out that i am using AWS API gateway and get the token from my header, he will be able to mimic exact same form submission from his domain or where ever he want right?? Hope i am clear enough. :)

Comment: You can do much more with custom authorizers than just check a custom header. In your question you asked "for example accept form submission only from one specific domain or something similar" and that is the sort of thing you would implement with a custom authorizer. Setting a JWT in a custom header is just the example given. Also, how do you expect someone to be able to "get the token from your header" if you are using SSL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116817/discussion-between-william-francis-gomes-and-mark-b).

Comment: @MarkB Can you give me one example of such setup? That will be much helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

The custom authorizer is able to validate your JWT token in a Lambda function. Instead of JWT token, you also are able to implement your own authorization strategy. It can be much securer than the API key. Here is [the documentation from API Gateway team](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html). It also provides the example to setup an authorizer which will validate a JWT token.